# OpenCV Adaptive Threshold Explanation

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Could anyone provide a mathematical explanation of the Adaptive Threshold function in OpenCV?

From the [OpenCV 3.1.0 Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) I found only this explanation:

> cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C : threshold value is the weighted sum of neighbourhood values where weights are a Gaussian window.

Which I do understand and can picture what the algorithm is doing for each pixel, just defining a mathematical solution for it is proving tougher than I thought.

I also found the code for it on the Github repo [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/994815fbd493973d0f9f9f7553a88f78d77f6374/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp#L1395) but, after trying to walk through the code, I've realised my knowledge of OpenCV doesn't quite cover it.

Also, any sources would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You said it, the function computes a weighted average in windows around every pixel. What don't you understand ?

Comment: Yes, as I said I understand what the algorithm is doing. It's just the mathematical representation that I am having trouble with.

Comment: `P'(x,y)= Sum i=-n,n, j=-n,n Wij P(x+i,y+j)`

Comment: And the representation for the weights as a 2D Gaussian? Also, why x+i and y+j? Shouldn't that be x_i and y_j?

Comment: No, you work in a square neighborhhood.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't know the formula for the 2D Gaussian distribution ? Google it.

Comment: Study Gaussian distribution and Gaussian blurring. Then known the difference between global and local methods in Image processing.